# Change the MahApps Metro Split ButtoniIcon size

Tags: wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to use the split button control described here:

http://mahapps.com/controls/split_dropdownbutton.html

I'm also using the MahApps resource pack with the icons collection. I want to re-size the control to a height of 40px, but the icon stays to its native height of 76px, resulting in it getting cropped, as shown below.

[image: Oversized Icon]

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `SplitButton` from `MahApps.Metro` has a property called `IconTemplate`. To this property you can assign a `DataTemplate` and there you can add almost arbitrary content, which will be put in place of the icon itself.

For example you could put a `Rectangle` control with fixed `Height` and/or `Width`. And setting its `OpacityMask` to your desired icon, will show the icon in smaller size.

In `XAML` it looks like this:

```
<controls:SplitButton Orientation="Horizontal">
<controls:SplitButton.IconTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Rectangle VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="35" Width="35" Fill="{DynamicResource BlackColorBrush}">
            <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
                <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource appbar_globe}" />
            </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
        </Rectangle>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:SplitButton.IconTemplate></controls:SplitButton>
```

`controls` is the alias for the `MahApps.Metro`-namespace and may differ in your project.